# Let's get critical: Jul 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Amateur Radio Stack Exchange](http://ham.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ham.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How does a Dual Band Handheld Antenna work?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1918/how-does-a-dual-band-handheld-antenna-work)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is this matching technique called?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-this-matching-technique-called)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's the pinout for "Kenwood" 2.5mm TRS/3.5 mm TRS connector?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-pinout-for-kenwood-2-5mm-trs-3-5-mm-trs-connector)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why are PL tones strange numbers?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/why-are-pl-tones-strange-numbers)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to center-feed a single wire dipole?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/how-to-center-feed-a-single-wire-dipole)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What rig or rigs are onboard the ISS?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/what-rig-or-rigs-are-onboard-the-iss)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [End-fed wire antenna lengths](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/end-fed-wire-antenna-lengths)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is the risk of damage to a transmitter due to a mismatched antenna at lower frequencies greater?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/why-is-the-risk-of-damage-to-a-transmitter-due-to-a-mismatched-antenna-at-lower)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Bicycle mobile antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/bicycle-mobile-antenna)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How does inductive base loading cause low feedpoint impedance in verticals?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-does-inductive-base-loading-cause-low-feedpoint-impedance-in-verticals)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Answer (score 3):

This is my perception of the state of the site:

**We have plenty of capacity to answer questions, but too low a rate of incoming questions, especially high-quality ones.**

(The places where the answers are bad are largely where the questions are bad; in particular, subjective questions tempting for “here's my experience” answers.)

The problem we need to solve is to get people to ask their questions here. I have no great ideas here, and I suspect that **this will be a particularly slow process no matter what**; I hope that the site is not shut down due to lack of activity too soon.